# Applying a Taylor series "with respect to $a/r$" and "around $0$"

Tags: terminology, taylor-expansion

My question is what does it mean

> applying a Taylor series with respect to something and around a point.

What is the difference?

Please explain it with the following example:

Apply a Taylor series expansion to $r'$ with respect to $a/r$ around $0$.
Only until the squared terms (inclusive).

Where $$r'^2 = a^2 + r^2 +2ar\sin(\theta)\cos(\alpha-\phi)$$

Comment: This is a polynomial in $a$, so its Taylor series is fairly straightforward.

Comment: As far as I know, they mean the same thing.

Comment: @nmasanta: In continuation of our previous conversation, if you're editing, don't forget titles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an easier example, let $f(x) = \sin(x)$. The Taylor series expansion of (or, I guess, in your above language 'to') $f$ with respect to $x$ around $0$ is the familar
$$ f(x) = x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} - \frac{x^7}{7!} + \dots$$

So you want to rewrite $r'$ in terms of $a/r$ and expand around 0.

Comment: thank you @bounceback for your answer, specially for specifying the idea about rewriting it, that was they key point.

Answer (score 6):

The "with respect to" specifies the variable whose powers appear in the series. "around" is the point near which you want an approximation. So your answer will look like
$$
c_o + c_1(a/r - 0) + c_2(a/r - 0)^2 + \text{ higher order terms}.
$$

(Of course the zeroes go away. I just put them in to illustrate "around $0$".)

Comment: thank you @ethan-bolker for the example!

Comment: by the way, in your answer is it r/a or you meant a/r ? thanks

Comment: @nachofest Yes,. Fixed thanks.